# Determine TCP/IP connection service port using Scapy pocket capturing

Tags: python, networking, scapy, tcp

I'm capturing packets using scapy and I'm trying to determine the service ports they are using. If I pick up a random packet I can simply look up the source and destination ports and tell if they match the known TCP ports, however, sometimes neither ports are in the known ports list, then my question is, how can I tell which one is the service port?

One way would be to determine which source initiated the connection then I can tell the service port since most of the time client connects to a server on some service port. So is there a way to tell which source initiated the connection by just looking at a random captured packet?

Comment: Hello ! Please elaborate and reformat your question ! It is currently very hard to read, and making it fancy will encourage people to help you !

Comment: Do you have an example of this packet capture?

Comment: @Cukic0d I reworded the question hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: @mr4kino So here i have this connecton: [---.---.-.12:47218]<->[---.---.---.188:5228] its using ports 47218 and 5228, how can i tell which one is a service port?

Comment: easy answer would to be google the low numbers port, 5228 here, and you can see it is a well known Google service.

Comment: and what is the reasoning behind that?